# Personal access tokens for Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: visual-studio

We are planning to use Visual Studio Team Services for our iOS project code repository on cloud.

I was able to successfully create "New Repository"

Now I am trying to push the code from XCode using below guide.

[Share your code in Git using Xcode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/share-your-code-in-git-xcode#create-a-new-vsts-repo)

When I try to upload the code it asks for username/password.

I need to create "personal access token" for the password.

But in VSTS -> Security i do not see an option to create personal access token.

[image: VSTS -> Security]

My question is how can i create "personal access token" ?

Comment: did you tried this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/share-your-code-in-git-vs ?

Comment: Sorry , I am doing it from my Mac machine and i do not have Visual studio installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://yourvstsaccount.visualstudio.com/_details/security/tokens

You're in the wrong security section